# Pass javascript variable to apex variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, dynamic-visualforce

I want to pass `encodeURIComponent("{!Account.Name}");` to some apex variable.
How can I achieve this?

I will be using ecnocded value in my page.

Comment: use apex:param to pass parameter in apex controller.

Comment: I need to set the value to encodeURIComponent("{!Account.Name}") before passing it to controller

Comment: why you need to pass this value to controller `{!Account.Name}` you can directly get this value from standard controller in apex..

Comment: I want the encoded {Account.Name} value to the controller

Answer (score 1):

Through the use of `actionFunction` with `<apex:param/>` you can pass value to the controler:

You can pass `value as "{!Account.Name}"` in the javascript method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function displayFunc(value)
      {
           passValueToController(encodeURIComponent(value));
      }        
</script>
<apex:actionFunction name="passValueToController" action="{!passValue}" immediate="true" reRender="form1">
     <apex:param id="selectedValue" name="selectedValue" value=""/> 
</apex:actionFunction>

public void passValue()
{
      fieldValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedValue');
      System.debug('fieldValue=' + fieldValue);     
}
```

Comment: I am a newbie , I dont understand this completely.
could you elaborate it more please

Comment: you can go through this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm